# Как мне с класса "билет" взять номер билета и перекинуть его в класс "задание"

Tags: .net

Как мне с класса "билет" взять номер билета и перекинуть его в класс "задание". И помогите сделать вывод
(кроме предующих выводов добавить вывод количества открытых вопросов и тестовых заданий.

```
class Exam
{
 public string ExamName { get; set; }
 private Ticket Ticket { get; set; }

public Exam(string examName, Ticket ticket)
{
    ExamName = examName;
    Ticket = ticket;
}

public override string ToString()
    => $"Название предмета: {ExamName}\n{Ticket}";
```

}

```
class Ticket
 {
 private Random _rnd = new Random();
 private static (int, string)[] _examDifficult = { (1, "Лёгкий"), (2, "Средний"), (3, "Тяжёлый") };

public int _TicketNumber { get; }
private string _ExamDifficult { get; }
private string _Test { get; } //типа тест

public Ticket(string test)
{
    _TicketNumber = _rnd.Next(1, 4);
    this._ExamDifficult = _examDifficult[_TicketNumber - 1].Item2;
    _Test = test;
}

public override string ToString()
    => $"Номер билета: {_TicketNumber}\n{_Test}\nСтепень сложности: {_ExamDifficult}\n";
  }
 abstract class Exercise
{
 public int _ExerciseCount { get; set; }

 public  void _Exercise()
{
    if (_TicketNumber == 1)
    {
        this._ExerciseCount = 7;
    }
    else if (_TicketNumber == 2)
    {
        this._ExerciseCount = 6;
    }
    else if (_TicketNumber == 2)
    {
        this._ExerciseCount = 8;
    }
    else
        this._ExerciseCount = 9;
}
}
class OpenQuestion : Exercise
{
public int _CountQuestion { get; set; }

public void Count()
{
    this._CountQuestion = _ExerciseCount % 2;
}
}
class TestExercise : Exercise
{
private int _CountTestE { get; set; }
public void Count()
{
    this._CountTestE = _ExerciseCount % 2;
}
}
```

Comment: Ticket._TicketNumber

Comment: @Виктор, теперь требует ссылку на обьект